# Mapped types: remove private interface

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

In TypeScript, private attributes are considered part of the shape (or interface) of a type.

```
class Person {
  constructor(private name: string, public age: number) { }
}
const p: Person = { age: 42 };
// Error: Property 'name' is missing.
```

This is valid, because TypeScript needs to keep track of privates.

```
class Person {
  constructor(private name: string, public age: number) { }
  equals(other: Person) {
    return this.name === other.name && this.age === other.age;
    // This is valid, because TypeScript kept track of the private `name` property!
  }
}
```

However, there usually you want to ignore the private interface. For example, when you're using dependency injection and unit testing.

```
class HttpClient {
   constructor(private log: Logger) {
   }
   async doGet(url: string) { 
      return (await fetch(url)).json();
   }
}

class MyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  // Implementation
}

// Unit test for MyService:
describe('MyService', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    const httpMock: HttpClient = { // ERROR: Property 'log' is missing
      doGet(url: string) {
         return Promise.resolve({ name: 'Han' });
      }
    };
    const sut = new MyService(httpMock);
  });
});
```

I know we could solve this by adding an interface `IHttpClient` which describes the public interface for an `HttpClient` and use that instead of the class type directly, but that is a lot of work and it need to be kept in sync manually.

Is there a way to remove all non-public properties from a type using a mapped type?

Something like:

```
type PublicInterface<T> = {
    [P in PublicNames<T>]: T[P];
}
```

So it could be used in places where you do not care about privates:

```
class MyService {
  constructor(private http: PublicInterface<HttpClient>) {
  }
  // Implementation
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`keyof` is smart enough to peek only public keys:

```
class Person {
  constructor(private name: string, public age: number) { }
}

type PublicInterface<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P];
}

const p: PublicInterface<Person> = { age: 42 }; // no error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGtY6EALogK7BEqIAUADogJYBuYR80aYAtvAFzTFGaAOYAaaLVIAjEA2DQwwvh1JcpSAJRZoAX2x7sRAJ612sabOABJNG0QAzMMHgAeACoA+aAF4suaADasNAMGADW8EYo9tBuALr8bkFxANz62NgEaMQS-OYycjZ2js4uCMjoXr6YCkr8ACwATLop0AD0bRwo0EiIVEA)

---

Or even shorter with [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk) utility (the result is equivalent to above mapped type):

```
type PublicInterface<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGtY6EALogK7BEqIAUADogJYBuYR80aYAtvAFzTFGaAOYAaaLVIAjEA2DQwwvh1JcpSAJRZoAX2x7sRAJ612sabOABJNG0QAzMMHgAeACoA+aAF44cgNbu4v7wRij20J4A3NjYBGjEEvzmMnI2do7OLgjI6F6+mApK-AAsAEy6UdAA9NUcKNBIiFRAA)

Comment: I've been working with typescript and mapped types for several years and only now notice this behavior ‍♂️

Thanks a lot!