# Error using private variables in typescript class in vue store (pinia)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

I have a node object that looks like this

```
export class Node {
    public position: Position;
    public radius: number;
    private languageStr: string = "py";
    private codeGenStrat: nodeGenStrategy = new pyNodeGenStrategy(this);
    color: string;
    name: string;
    id: number;
    publishers: Array<number>;
    subscribers: Array<number>;
    parameters: Array<NodeParameter>;
    constructor(id: number, x: number, y: number, name: string, radius:number=50, color:string="skyblue", language:string="py", 
    publishers: Array<number>=[], subscribers: Array<number>=[], parameters: Array<NodeParameter>=[]
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.position = new Position(x, y);
        this.name = name;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
        this.language = language; // either "py" or "cpp"
        this.publishers = publishers;
        this.subscribers = subscribers;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

In my vue store, I have an array of these node objects. the vue store looks something like this

```
export const useNodeCanvasStore = defineStore({
    id: 'nodeCanvas',
    state: (): State => { return {
        nodes : [],
        topics : [],
        services : [],
        actions: [],

    }},
    getters: {},
    actions: {
        getNode(id: number): Node {
            const node: Node | undefined = this.nodes.find((node: Node) => node.id == id);
            if (!node) {
                throw new StoreError(`Could not find node with id ${id}`);
            }
            return node;
        }
    }
}
```

where the State object looks like this

```
interface State {
    nodes : Array<Node>;
    topics : Array<Topic>;
    services : Array<Service>;
    actions: Array<Action>;
}
```

in the line `this.nodes.find((node: any) => node.id == id);` however, I get this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value: { position: { x: number; y: number; }; radius: number; color: string; name: string; id: number; publishers: number[]; subscribers: number[]; parameters: { name: string; type: string; value: string; id: number; }[]; ... 11 more ...; toJSON: () => { ...; }; }, index: number, obj: { ...; }[]) => value is Node, thisArg?: any): Node | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(node: Node) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { position: { x: number; y: number; }; radius: number; color: string; name: string; id: number; publishers: number[]; subscribers: number[]; parameters: { name: string; type: string; value: string; id: number; }[]; ... 11 more ...; toJSON: () => { ...; }; }, index: number, obj: { ...; }[]) => value is Node'.
      Types of parameters 'node' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type '{ position: { x: number; y: number; }; radius: number; color: string; name: string; id: number; publishers: number[]; subscribers: number[]; parameters: { name: string; type: string; value: string; id: number; }[]; ... 11 more ...; toJSON: () => { ...; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': languageStr, codeGenStrat
  Overload 2 of 2, '(predicate: (value: { position: { x: number; y: number; }; radius: number; color: string; name: string; id: number; publishers: number[]; subscribers: number[]; parameters: { name: string; type: string; value: string; id: number; }[]; ... 11 more ...; toJSON: () => { ...; }; }, index: number, obj: { ...; }[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): { ...; } | undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(node: Node) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { position: { x: number; y: number; }; radius: number; color: string; name: string; id: number; publishers: number[]; subscribers: number[]; parameters: { name: string; type: string; value: string; id: number; }[]; ... 11 more ...; toJSON: () => { ...; }; }, index: number, obj: { ...; }[]) => unknown'.
      Types of parameters 'node' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type '{ position: { x: number; y: number; }; radius: number; color: string; name: string; id: number; publishers: number[]; subscribers: number[]; parameters: { name: string; type: string; value: string; id: number; }[]; ... 11 more ...; toJSON: () => { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Node'.ts(2769)
```

When I make the private properties of the node public, the error goes away. I also have similar functions for the topics and services arrays and they work perfectly fine. Why does having private properties cause this error? Is there any way to still have private properties and not have an error here?

Comment: Probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389559/mapped-types-remove-private-interface

Comment: Private members make a type incompatible. This is used sometimes for a purpose to avoid duck typing. There are many problems associated with classes in Vue, I'd generally advise against using them. E.g. `codeGenStrat: nodeGenStrategy = new pyNodeGenStrategy(this)` will result in codeGenStrat being non-reactlve. You could write it as factory function without losing anything.