# Vue 3 ref and reactive remove private typescript class properties from passed object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

If an object has a private property or method and passed to `ref()` or `reactive()` the result proxy does not contain private properties anymore.

Having this class :

```
class Pirate {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  private dream : string;

  constructor(name: string, age: number, dream: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.dream = dream;
  }
}
```

Creating a ref `Pirate` object is not of type `Ref<Pirate>` and will cause this Typescript error :

> Property 'dream' is missing...

Example [here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

I need to create a reactive object and I need to keep the private properties as private. is it possible is Vue 3 ?

The same issue happens with `reactive()` too.

Comment: The question doesn't mention TS, while this is TS problem. Private fields are known to force type incompatibility in TS and can be used for this purpose. You'll need a separate interface to type it, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389559/mapped-types-remove-private-interface Generally classes are PITA in Vue, their usage is possible but hardly justified.

Comment: Would `Ref<Partial<Pirate>>` work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I got inspired from @alex87's comment, and [Mapped types: remove private interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389559/mapped-types-remove-private-interface), and have a potential solution:

```
Pick<Pirate, keyof Pirate>
```

If this is repeated needed, you could define a helper type, following that SO answer:

```
type PublicInterface<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;
```

(All credits to the others.)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to import `Ref`, because `const captain = ref(...)` will be `Ref`.
If you set `private dream`, you can use this only inside`Pirate` class.
If you want to get `dream` outside the class, do something like this: `getDream() { return this.dream }`.
[**Vue SFC Playground**](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The example I showed is an abstraction of a much more complicated code I have. I only need dream internally that's why its a private property. And I added Ref to show that the returned type is not the one expected. In my real code I need to pass Ref<Pirate> to a fucntion and TS is not happy because the type is missing all the private properties.